# .htaccess 301 redirect for URL ignoring its parameters

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

File redirects

```
Redirect 301 /products.php http://example.com/product_123.php
```

and domain redirects

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com/
```

are easy. However, I want to redirect some URLs ignoring all parameters, i.e.

```
example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3?pagination=1
example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3?ref=2
example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3?day=Monday
example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3?referer=Google 
example.com/slug1/slug2/slug3?referer=Facebook
... etc
```

should all redirect to

```
example.com/slug4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's where you should use a [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directive with regex matching instead of the plain `Redirect`.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 "/slug1/slug2/slug3(.*)$" "/slug4"
```

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 "/slug1/slug2/slug3(.*)$" ...` is the same as a "plain `Redirect`" (ie. `Redirect 301 /slug1/slug2/slug3 ...`), since `Redirect` is _prefix matching_.

Comment: @w3d Yes but unlike the normal Redirect the above will strip the  arguments. - A plain redirect would redirect `/slug1/slug2/slug3?pagination=1` to `/slug4?pagination=1`, by using the regex grouping allows to redirect `/slug1/slug2/slug3?pagination=1` to `/slug4`,

Comment: `RedirectMatch` behaves the same as `Redirect` with respect to the query string - it's passed through to the target URL unaltered (unless you explicitly include a query string on the target URL). However, to _completely_ remove the query string you would need to use mod_rewrite (as mentioned in my answer). "by using the regex grouping" - The `RedirectMatch` (and `Redirect`) directive only matches against the URL-path, which notably excludes the query string, so given the above example URLs, the "regex group" `(.*)` actually matches nothing (and is therefore superfluous).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simply *ignore all parameters*, then you can still use a standard `Redirect`, because it is *prefix matching* and does not match against the query string anyway. For example:

```
Redirect 301 /slug1/slug2/slug3 /slug4
```

The above `Redirect` would 301-redirect all the URLs in the question (ie. all URLs that start `/slug1/slug2/slug3`) to `/slug4`.

However, any query string on the requested URL will also be passed through to the target URL unaltered. So, `/slug1/slug2/slug3?ref=2` will be redirected to `/slug4?ref=2`. If this is undesirable, and you wish to remove the query string entirely<sup>***1**</sup>, then you will need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`), rather than mod_alias (ie. `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch`, as suggested in the other answer) in order to explicitly remove the query string completely from the target URL. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^slug1/slug2/slug3$ /slug4? [R=301,L]
```

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution will result in the query string being removed from the target URL (you could alternatively use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+). The query string is not matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so there is nothing extra you need to do in this respect, unless you needed to match specific query strings, or only when there is actually a query string (the above will match regardless of whether a query string is present or not).

An additional caveat with switching to a mod_rewrite redirect is that you should ideally change any existing mod_alias redirects to the equivalent mod_rewrite syntax. This is to avoid any potential conflicts since the two modules execute at different times.

<sup>***1**</sup> Note that you can simply append a `?` (ie. an empty query string) on the end of the target URL with the `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives. However, the trailing `?` is actually included in the redirected URL, as opposed to be being removed entirely, as with a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive.